# Are there different approaches to this definite integral problem?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Here is the problem:
$$I=\int_0^\pi e^{\cos{x}}\cos{(\sin{x})}~\mathrm{d}x$$
There is an elegant solution for this: 
Firstly, the function to be integrated is apparently even. Hence,
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{\cos{x}}\cos{(\sin{x})}~\mathrm{d}x$$
One can then consider the function to be integrated as the real part of $\displaystyle{e^{\cos x}\left(\cos(\sin x)+i\sin(\sin x)\right)}$, in this case we can write
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\Re\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{\cos x}\left(\cos(\sin x)+i\sin(\sin x)\right)~\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}\Re\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{\cos x+i\sin x}~\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}\Re\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{e^{ix}}~\mathrm{d}x$$
Set $z=e^{ix}$, so that $\mathrm{d}z=iz\mathrm{d}x$. Hence,
$$\Re\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{e^{ix}}~\mathrm{d}x=\Re\oint\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{e^z}{iz}~\mathrm{d}z$$
One may recall the Cauchy integration formula. In this case we let $f(z)=e^z$, then
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}~\mathrm{d}z=f(z_0)$$
Now set $z_0=0$, it is immediately obvious that:
$$\oint\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{e^z}{z}~\mathrm{d}z=2\pi i$$
Hence,
$$I= \frac{1}{2}\Re\oint\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{e^z}{iz}~\mathrm{d}z=\color{blue}{\pi}$$
Different approaches for this problem are expected here.

Comment: This should answer your question: [Integral with Composite Trigonometric Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851118/integral-with-composite-trigonometric-function) (chosen among the many duplicates [found using Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_0%5E%5Cpi%20e%5E%7B%5Ccos%7Bx%7D%7D%5Ccos%7B(%5Csin%7Bx%7D)%7D~%5Cmathrm%7Bd%7Dx%24&p=1))